# Yes/ No Dialog box before redirection

Tags: javascript, dialog

I have a PHP-based form that will insert data into a database.

What I want to happen is when I click the submit button, a popup box would appear with a yes and no. If yes is chosen, then it will redirect to the page that will insert the form data into the database.

How can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: Quality questions show the code that you've tried and ask a question about specifically where you got stuck.  If you haven't yet done any research about how to solve this issue, then you should go do that first.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with js and jQuery. I don't know your context, but it might be like this:

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html('<div><h6>Do you really want to do this?</h6></div>')
    .dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: 'Title',
    buttons: {
        Yes: function () {
            doFunctionForYes();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        No: function () {
            doFunctionForNo();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
$('#msg').hide();

function doFunctionForYes() {
    alert("Yes");
    $('#msg').show();
}

function doFunctionForNo() {
    alert("No");
    $('#msg').show();
}
```